# cellEditing plugin for ExtJS 4 causes 'event is undefined' error when closing tab panel tab

Tags: plugins, grid, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a grid in a tabpanel. I click a row in the grid and a new tabpanel opens with details for the clicked item. The details on the new tab opened can be edited and then sent back to the server through CRUD routines. I am using the cellEditing plugin, and it seems to be working fine to edit the cell, but when I close the window after performing edits I get an error "event is undefined' Why might this be occurring? Is there a way to edit a cell in a grid without using the cellEditing plugin? ...or maybe a way to fix the plugin to get it to work? I am using the plugin in the Ext.apply section of my initComponent for the grid.

I am using ext-all-debug.js and the error looks to be coming from an area where a function call is for 'closeListener', from line 13367 in ext-all-debg.js I do not believe I have any listeners on the page, so why is this error coming up on tab close?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing code.  Can't tell much more than exactly what the error says... some code is listening for the 'close' event on a component that doesn't fire that event.  Please post some code if you can.

Comment: The site won't let me post any code

Comment: Well, it has been all weekend. has no one had an opportunity to look at this code and see where the error might be? If anyone has issue with finding the code JSFiddle then let me know.